# jQuery mobile: Radio buttons not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

There's something wrong with my code and I can't figure out what it is. I am using jQuery mobile to generate radio buttons forms. However, it is not working as expected. It appears just like this (picture link: http://tinypic.com/r/4q0os8/5 ) while it should list all the radio buttons below each other

Generated HTML:

```
 <div data-role="content">
                <h3>
                    Answer This Question
                </h3>
                <form action="storeresponse.php" method="GET" ajax-data="false">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                            <legend>
                                What is your favorite food?                            </legend>

                                <input id="radio1" value="" name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                <label for="radio1">Pizza</label>

                                <input id="radio1" value="" name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                <label for="radio1">Pasta</label>

                                <input id="radio1" value="" name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                <label for="radio1">Chicken wings</label>

                                <input id="radio1" value="" name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                <label for="radio1">Noodles</label>
                                                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right"
                               value="Submit">
                    </div>

                </form>
```

It's generating the same ID for  each radio button while I've added `$i++`

Comment: Can you post also generated HTML? It will be much easier to find an error.

Comment: Sorry I didn't meant that. I was wondering about generated HTML when your page is displayed. If I can see what was generated I can tell you what to look for.

Comment: Generated HTML

         `<div>
                                         <input id="radio1" value="<br />
    <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: optionName in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PhoneClassmate_zympic\question.php</b> on line <b>87</b><br />
    " name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                    <label for="radio1">Pizza</label>
                                    </div>`
 I found an error in the generated HTML. It doesn't identify a value.

Comment: Well that is your problem, it is causing a HTML structure to be incorrect before jQM can enhance its styles.

Comment: Ok, I took care of that. Now it does this: `<input id="radio1" value="" name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                <label for="radio1">Pizza</label>
                                 
                                <input id="radio1" value="" name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                <label for="radio1">Pasta</label>` Notice the id for each radio button, it is the same while I've told PHP to increment it in the while loop. How to fix that?

Comment: because you have `$i = 1` inside while loop. you have to put it outside while. it resets `$i` to `1` each time it loops.

Comment: Lol, Shukran Omar! I didn't notice that.

Comment: Afwan sis :) Allah ysam7ek 3ala heik 3amleh lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Additional tip:** `$i` should be placed outside `while loop`.

---

In your case, you need to enhance the markup of `contorlgroup` and `radio buttons` using `create` method.

jQuery Mobile offers an easy to enhance dynamically inserted elements and make them look as static ones this way.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5aePn/)**

For creating and enhancing Checkbox / Radio buttons:

```
$('[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
```

To enhance `controlgroup`

```
$('[data-role=controlgroup]').controlgroup().trigger('create');
```

Comment: I don't think this is it. My above code generates the same ID for each radio button. I will update my code.

Comment: @ElShaikhaSue keefek? if radio buttons look partially styled, then this is your problem, you need to enhance your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `<input...>` and `<label>` tags with `<p>` tags:

```
<?php
                        $sql = "SELECT option_description FROM options WHERE question_id = '$qid'";
                        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                            $i = 1;
                            $optionName = $row['0'];
                            ?> 
                            <p>
                                <input id="<?php echo 'radio' . $i ?>" value="<?php echo $optionName ?>" name="option" data-theme="c" type="radio">
                                <label for="<?php echo 'radio' . $i ?>"><?php echo $optionName; ?></label>
                            </p>
                            <?php $i++;
                        } ?>
```

Comment: You must have something else in your code, maybe jquery / javascript which is stripping or not applying formatting to the labels and input :-/